# What is the use of cast in MySQL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I wrote the code in CodeIgniter.
what is the meaning of cast in the following step

```
$this->db->select('cast(cls.search_last_run as Date);
```

If i want to get present time in $lastrun, i used the following code.Will date(now()) gives the present time?

```
$lastrun="cast(cls.search_last_run  as DATE) > now())";
```

Comment: The cast turns the `search_last_run` into a date.  Normally, this removes the time component on the value.  `now()` returns the current date/time on the database server.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. $lastrun will be a string containing a part of an sql expression.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff...

Comment: What is the diff between now() and date(now())

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're askiing but `CAST()` is a MySQL function that will cast the values of `cls.search_last_run` to a Date format (`yyyy-mm-dd`) if you want the present date in Date format you can use `CAST(NOW() as Date)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: Hi @shadow pls answer the question What is the diff between now() and date(now())

Comment: Have you fired up your commands in a console? If you run `SELECT NOW(), DATE(NOW());` you will see that `NOW()` returns the current time as well while `DATE(NOW())` behaves as explained above.

Comment: Will the following line produce the diff between last_run_search and present date         datediff(now(),cls.search_last_run) >= 1)

Comment: I don't know what's in your database so it would be easier if you test it :) However as I suspect `search_last_run` to be DateTime this looks pretty fine yes. `DATEDIFF` can work with both types (Date and DateTime).